# What is the distribution of $N = \inf \{ n ≥ 1,~~ 0 < X^2_n + Y^2_n< 1 \}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Define two independent sequences $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of independent and identical uniform random variables over $[−1, 1]$.

Assuming $N = \inf \{ n ≥ 1,~~ 0 < X^2_n + Y^2_n< 1 \}$, find the distribution of $N$.

The solution of the exercise is $$p(N=n)=\left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
and so the distribution is geometric $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I would like to understand how the above probability was found.

Answer (score 3):

Lets compute the probability $P(X_n^2+Y_n^2<1)$ as being the area of the unit circle divided by the area of the $[-1,1]^2$ square, that is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Now since the $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are i.i.d, we get
\begin{align}
P(N=n)&=P(X_1^2+Y_1^2\geq 1)\cdots P(X_{n-1}^2+Y_{n-1}^2\geq 1) \cdot P(X_n^2+Y_n^2<1)\\
&= \left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n-1}\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}

The event $\{X_n^2+Y_n^2=0\}=\{ X_n=Y_n=0 \}$ is a zero probability event and doesn't change anything in the above computation.

Comment: could you please clarify more the first line? why to consider a circle and a square? which intuition lead us to think in this way? thanks a lot

Comment: $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent uniform random variable over $[-1,1]$ so they distribution joint is uniform over the $[-1,1]$ square. Now since the region $X_n^2+Y_n^2\leq 1$ is the unit disc, it's probability (since it is uniform) is the the area of the circle normalized by the the area of the square. Is that clearer ? In general when it is uniform you should think about areas and relative areas.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot